# First Irish color feature?

Tags: cinema-history

What was the first Irish color feature film? On google I found information about the first color footage, but nothing about a feature film, a movie. The film should be one that the Irish film historians and/or public tend to regard as the first color film of their national cinema.

Comment: Great question!

Comment: Please define your terms...What does "Irish color feature" mean. Produced by Ireland? Shot in Ireland? [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Irish_films) has a great resource...

Comment: http://filmireland.net/2017/06/14/early-irish-cinema-a-new-industry-the-film-company-of-irelands-first-season/

Comment: Thanks for the links! I'm looking for the first Irish color feature, which the Irish consider as the first color feature film of their national cinema

Comment: Surprised no one seems to know... (the links don't address the topic)